# Make text and custom fields sortable using Laravel Nova Indicator Field?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-nova

I would like to make my text and custom fields sortable. But I haven't found a single page which explains me how this works.

Either these:

```
Text::make('Type', function () {
    return $this->productType->name;
})
    ->sortable(),
```

or this is working:

```
Text::make('Type', function () {
    return $this->productType->name;
})
    ->sortable(function () {
        return $this->productType->name;
    }),
```

Do you guys have an idea how to make those text fields sortable?
Also, is it possible to make custom fields sortable like this one?

```
Indicator::make('Status', function() {
    return $this->postStatus->status;
}),
```

This is from this package: https://github.com/inspheric/nova-indicator-field

Kind regards and thanks!

Comment: Computed fields are not sortable - https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#computed-fields

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine method `indexQuery` in your resource(Laravel Nova model) and load fields that you want to make sortable in index page

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->addSelect([
        'name' => ProductType::select('name')
            ->whereColumn('product_id', 'products.id')
            ->limit(1),
    ]);
}
```

> `->whereColumn('product_id', 'products.id')`, statement changes depend on the main entity(in this case Product haveMany ProductType))

And in Laravel Nova 4 you can use Badge Field for showing status [laravel nova badge field docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/fields.html#badge-field)

```
Fields\Badge::make(__('Status'), 'status')
   ->textAlign('left')
   ->labels([
     'closed' => 'Closed',
     'canceled' => 'Canceled',
   ])
   ->map([
     'closed' => 'success',
     'canceled' => 'danger',
   ])
   ->withIcons()
   ->sortable(),
```

This badges look very nice

[image: how badges look like]